# Difference between calculated ema through various python libraries, formulas available and the ema from various trading sites

Tags: python, stock, ta-lib

I have used probably all available python libraries to calculate the exponential moving average(ema) of stocks. I have used ta-lib, pandas_ta etc. for this. But there is always a mismatch between the values provided by the libraries and the values listed on trading sites like binance etc. I am using the maximum historical data available for each stock i.e from when the stock IPO'd.
Can anyone please help?? It has already taken me days... but to no avail.

Comment: We can help if we know specifically what to help with. Your question is not specific enough. You need to provide some code so we can see what you have done so far and we will be able to help. Please read How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Give an example with ema of different libraries on one kind of data.

Comment: Well i got it.... thanks anyways!!